# How could contents of file in git working tree not reflect head commit?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Our enterprise uses BitBucket Server as our SoR for git.  That probably doesn't matter, but I'm just setting the background.

In the last couple of days a couple different developers have shown me issues with their git commits and pull requests that seem impossible.  The first one showed me a pull request, on which he had just executed a merge from his target branch to his pull request branch.  It showed one file with merge conflicts (there were 3 different files with merge conflicts) that mystified him (and me), because he had made no changes in that particular file in his pull request.  The merge conflict clearly showed the two opposing change blocks, but he had made neither of those change blocks.

Today, a developer showed me a situation where the contents of the file in the working tree does not reflect the content of the HEAD commit.  We saw this in the BitBucket gui view, and in our local repositories (after doing a pull).  We verified that the commit she expected to see was the last commit on the branch, but the file in the working tree simply didn't have those changes.  Again, I see the exact same symptoms when I view that file in my local repository.

In the BitBucket GUI, we even did a "Diff to Previous", and it clearly shows the latest changes that we expect to see in the working tree, but when we look at the raw file, it doesn't have those changes.

Is this something that happens from time to time?  What exactly has happened here, and what is a reasonable path forward?

Comment: What can you discover if you `git blame` the files in conflict? That should show you the commit for each change & help then make sense of what's happened.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the first incident. The evidence for that is gone, unfortunately. The developer couldn't wait.

Comment: Didn't they pushed using `-f` (force)? If someone made a push force from another terminal the both terminals might end up with the HEAD commit but based on Git behavior, after a push force the branch kinda becomes a new one in the Git branch multiverse (I mean a new history pipeline with same name)... Maybe check their reflogs and check what they have done...

Comment: *Is this something that happens from time to time?* No, never. *What exactly has happened here?* How do we know without looking at the repository, the pull requests, local configuration and code?